# How to increase stack size in macOS for running C/C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, macos

So, I have to increase my Stack Size for running a C/C++ program. Now, from my online search I have found conflicting answers. The general way though is to increase it using `ulimits`.
I can see that my initial stack size is 8176 KBs, Now, I first tried to increase it to 18,000 KBs, it seems to have worked. But, I can't get it to exceed the Hard Limit, is there a way to increase this hard limit in MacOS?

```
vedantamohapatra@Vedantas-MacBook-Air ~ % ulimit -s
8176
vedantamohapatra@Vedantas-MacBook-Air ~ % ulimit -s 18000
vedantamohapatra@Vedantas-MacBook-Air ~ % ulimit -s      
18000
vedantamohapatra@Vedantas-MacBook-Air ~ % ulimit -Hs
65520
vedantamohapatra@Vedantas-MacBook-Air ~ % ulimit -s 65521
ulimit: value exceeds hard limit
```

Comment: You probably should design your code such that it does not need  so much stack space.

Comment: Why do you think that you have to increase your stack size?

Comment: Related to increasing the limit on macOS: [https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32235/how-to-properly-increase-a-ulimit-n-limits](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32235/how-to-properly-increase-a-ulimit-n-limits)

Comment: @eerorika Actually in many Contests like HackerCup, and HashCode the Stack Size used is quite large sometimes. Many of people use like 1GB of Stack size in Linux, and Windows, but in MacOS I am not able to increase it beyond this.

Comment: @drescherjm I checked the article you posted here, But I am not able to find any mention of hard limits, or even if this can be increased.

Comment: This answer mentions hard limits: [https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312010/346266](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312010/346266) ***Note: You can use extra -S parameter for a soft or -H for the hard limit.***

Comment: @drescherjm I had also earlier tried running the command for hard limit but this is what I get ulimit -Hs 1000000
ulimit: can't raise hard limits. So, basically we can't raise the hard limit?

Comment: @VedantaMohapatra: "*Actually in many Contests like HackerCup, and HashCode the Stack Size used is quite large sometimes.*" Then stop using those "contests". 8 MB of stack space is more than enough for any reasonable application. Contests that encourage the use of bad programming practices should be avoided.

Comment: @VedantaMohapatra, normally the maximum stack size, as in your Mac, is set to 8Mb.  It's quite rare that a program needs a bigger one... I have been running programs that demanded 15Gb and more of heap, but run perfectly without changing the maximum stack size.  You should not have that demand.  I don't know where you have seen that 1Gb of stack size is inormal... but I can assure you that it isnt.  The Hard limit requires 1) Root privileges to be raised and 2) Hardware limits over that size, to be possible.  Check what is your case, but a good hint is to redesign your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can increase the stack size of a macOS program by passing `-stack_size size` to the linker when linking the program. `ulimit` does not change the stack size that a program requests; it changes what requests the system will grant.

Increasing the stack size is generally a bad or incorrect approach in solving online judging or contests. There are two solutions that are usually intended: Find another algorithm that requires less memory or use dynamic allocation. Contest problems are often designed so that naïve approaches require excessive amounts of memory but there are smart approaches that do not.

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly we need to do? Like is -stack_size a command on zsh?

Comment: @VedantaMohapatra: When you link the program with the `ld` command, use the switch `-stack_size` in the command, followed by a hexadecimal numeral. If you do not use the `ld` command, look up the documentation for the command you use to see how to ask it to pass options to the linker. However, note that, as stated in this answer, **increasing the stack size is likely the wrong approach**.

Comment: I actually use VS Code to code, but I when I use the terminal to execute a C++ code, I basically use something like g++ filename.cpp. Can you mention what change in this command should I have to do to get the required change?

Comment: @VedantaMohapatra: For `g++`, try `-Wl,-stack_size -Wl,3f00000`.